# Key vault task showing error in YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-keyvault

I am using Key Vault task in Azure YAML pipeline to download the secrets, but it shows error under "SecretsFilter" and "RunAsPreJob". But this works after removing those 2 fields. Ideally they should work as they have been added as tasks and are shown as required fields in task.

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xyz'
    KeyVaultName: 'abc'
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: true
```

Comment: What is the error? You need to provide as much information as possible if you want to receive help.

Comment: Hi Ronak, have you tired Daniel's reply change your YAML pipeline. If issue persist, could you please attach your full YAML file here for future troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi Ronak, any update on this,did you get a chance to implement the solution that Daniel suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Case matters. Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet).

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 
    keyVaultName: 
    secretsFilter: '*'
    runAsPreJob: false # Azure DevOps Services only
```

Note the lower-case letters.

Comment: The same is what we get when extracted from the UI of a release task